# No Users settings on my Samsung Galaxy tablet running on Android 4.4.2

Tags: samsung, settings, multi-user

On my Samsung Galaxy tablet running on Android 4.4.2, I don't see any way to manage multiple users on this device.

From what I can find, there is suppose to be a Users settings menu item, but it's not there.

What's the possible reason, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not there, then either your ROM is messed up somehow, or the menu item is hidden extremely well, or Samsung chose not to include the Users functionality in your ROM, period.

There *is* a way to force your device to display the Users setting screen; working or not. You just need to launch the `Users` activity in `com.android.settings`. One way to do that is by installing Nova Launcher, adding the Activities widget to the homescreen, and choosing that activity from the list.

If that still doesn't work, then your device really does not include the Users functionality (which is surprising, as it's a tablet).